# $("#form").attr("method", "post") is In java Script ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Grid view where I have a hyper link button which displays ID, by  clicking on it I make a Ajax call to the server and get the specific URL to navigate against of the ID. After the Ajax call complete I call the following 
Codes to open the respective page in New Tab/Window.

```
function RedirectPageUrl(rqstID) {           
$("#formMain").attr("action", rqstID);
$("#formMain").attr("method", "post");
$("#formMain").attr('target', '_blank');
$("#formMain").submit();
return false;
}
```

Here my problem is after clicking on the First hyperlink button things are working perfectly but then onwards whenever I click on any control (say Button)the previous opened form opens up.
How to get rid of it any idea??

Answer (score 1):

Because you have modified the `action` and other attributes of the main form on your page which I guess is the same `#formMain'. So next time whenever you try to click on any button which postbacks to the server it submits the form to the action set by previous`RedirectPageUrl` method call.

You can try something like this which is basically using a different form for redirecting to another page. This way the main `form` remains unchanged and other functionalities on the page are not affected.

```
function RedirectPageUrl(rqstID) {           
    var $redirectForm = $('#redirectForm');
    if($redirectForm.length == 0){
        $redirectForm = $('<form id="redirectForm" method="post" target="_blank" />')
                        .appendTo(document.body);
    }
    $redirectForm
         .attr("action", rqstID)
         .submit();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Here #formMain is in master page so by adding new form to redirect I may loose all the look and feel of Master page.So is it not possible to revert back the Action attribute after Redirecting.

Comment: Add a new form at the end of the body element will not affect your page. Try it.

Comment: So If I got you properly I don't have to make any changes in my master pages HTML right??? #redirectForm will be created run time???

Comment: The above solution met my requirement but not completely. Now by clicking on any control (say Button) the previous opened form does not opens up but by clicking on any control the Web page is getting re initialize(control flow is entering inside If(!IsPostBack) code block instead of IsCallBack code block)